# Find a time in some text, allowing for multiple formats

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula. 
=INDEX(Lookups!$L$1:$L$726,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(Lookups!$L$1:$L$726,$A1)),-1,1)*(ROW(Lookups!$L$1:$L$726)-ROW(Lookups!$L$1)+1)))

The idea is to pick up the time for a certain item from an email (already parsed into google sheets). The emails come in various formats so I'm unable to specify the location in the the text string to look at specifically.

The times are not always written in a conventional time format either so as you can see from the formula there are 726 possibilities that I work with. For example, sometimes the time could be written as 13:15 and others as 1:15 or even 1.15 or 1-15 etc etc.

The issue I have is that the above formula seems to start with the smallest string possible and work 'upwards', therefore picking up 3:15 from the email string rather than the full time string which is 13:15. Is there a way I can amend the formula to search for the longest string first, in that example looking for 13:15 and then only searching for 3:15 if the prior is not found.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to reorder those 726 possibilities so that you have the longer ones first. You can do it by creating another column with `=len(L1)`, copying that formula down, and sorting the range by this new column in descending order.

But it would be easier to use [regexextract](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) instead, because regular expressions are designed to solve the problem you are facing. For example,

```
=regexextract(L1, "\b\d{1,2}[:.-]\d{1,2}\b")
```

picks up all of the variants 1:15, 13:15, 1-15 or 13.15. (It looks for the following sequence: word boundary, 1-2 digits, one of characters :, ., -, then 1-2 digits, and another word boundary.) The match is greedy, so it will find 13:15 when it's there, not just 3:15.

A more complex form

```
=regexextract(L1, "(?i)\b\d{1,2}[:.-]\d{1,2} ?(?:am|pm)?\b")
```

also supports "am" or "pm" after the time, case-insensitive and possibly separated by a space from the digits.

This can be refined further, for example the hours part would be more precisely stated as `[0-2]?\d` instead of `\d{1,2}`, and the minutes part as  `[0-6]?\d`.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks zaq.